# Rails: Associating Models at Long-Range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, has-many-through, model-associations

**RAILS - LONG-RANGE MODEL ASSOCIATIONS**

Basically, I'm having some difficulty with `has_many :through =>`

I have four models of interest:

1. Crosswords
2. Cells
3. Clues
4. Words

A Crossword has many Cells, a Cell has many Clues, a Clue belongs to a Word

Or, visually:

```
Crossword --< Cell --< Clue >-- Word
```

Right now I have my associations set up to allow me to get from Crossword to Clues in one query, but I don't know how to set them up to get me from Crossword all the way to Words in one query.

```
class Crossword
  has_many :cells
  has_many :clues, through: :cells
end
```

So Crossword.first.clues works! But when I try the following...

```
class Crossword
  ...
  has_many :words, through: :clues
end
```

...no dice.

I can inelegantly work around the issue using `.map`:

```
Crossword.first.clues.map{|clue| clue.word}
```

But I'd *really* like to figure out how this is done using appropriate ActiveRecord Associations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

**EDIT:** Here are the results of my sample queries:

```
> Crossword.first.clues

=> [<Clue id: 4, content: "ExampleABC123", word_id: 2 >]
```

and

```
> Crossword.first.clues.words

=> Crossword Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "crosswords".* FROM "crosswords" ORDER BY "crosswords"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> Clue Load (4.3ms)  SELECT "clues".* FROM "clues" INNER JOIN "cells" ON "clues"."id" = "cells"."clue_id" WHERE "cells"."crossword_id" = $1  [["crossword_id", 32]]
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `words' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Clue:0x007fd000d5e238>
```

Comment: SO what are you getting when you try the code above? Some error, empty results? Have you tried running `crossword.words.to_sql` in console?

Comment: Alright, well after uploading my output, I finally found my problem and it's a stupid one. Instead of inputting `Crossword.first.words`, I was inputting `Crossword.first.clues.words`. My associations are actually fine, I'm just dumb.

Comment: I'll document my errors and mark this closed. Sorry the trouble, folks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was *not* my associations, it was my input.

My associations were as follows:

```
class Crossword < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  has_many :cells
  has_many :clues, through: :cells
  has_many :words, through: :clues
...
end
```

This accurately modeled my system, but when I was trying to get the words for a crossword, I kept on asking for `example_crossword.clues.words` instead of `example_crossword.words`

Case closed!